# JQuery/Javascript Function breaks $(this) (I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was refactoring my code *(I think refactoring is the right word)*, so I used a function so I wouldn't repeat myself so much. But I think the function messed up my $(this).

**The part of my code thats commented out works**

**I think my problem is in the function at `disabled = this;`**

```
var active = '.teachers';
var disabled = '.teacher-link';
var width = $('.teachers .staff-outer-container').children().size() * 180;
$('.staff-outer-container').css('width', width + 'px');

/* BELOW IS COMMENTED OUT
$('.teacher-link').click(function() {
    if (active != '.teachers') {
        $(active).hide();
        active = '.teachers';
        $(active).show();
        width = $('.teachers .staff-outer-container').children().size() * 180;
        $('.teachers .staff-outer-container').css('width', width + 'px');
        $(disabled).removeClass('active').addClass('clickable');
        disabled = this;
        $(disabled).removeClass('clickable').addClass('active');
        $('#type').text('Teachers');
    }
});
$('.admin-link').click(function() {
    if (active != '.administrators') {
        $(active).hide();
        active = '.administrators';
        $(active).show();
        width = $('.administrators .staff-outer-container').children().size() * 180;
        $('.administrators .staff-outer-container').css('width', width + 'px');
        $(disabled).removeClass('active').addClass('clickable');
        disabled = this;
        $(disabled).removeClass('clickable').addClass('active');
        $('#type').text('Administrators');
    }
});
$('.support-link').click(function() {
    if (active != '.support') {
        $(active).hide();
        active = '.support';
        $(active).show();
        width = $('.support .staff-outer-container').children().size() * 180;
        $('.support .staff-outer-container').css('width', width + 'px');
        $(disabled).removeClass('active').addClass('clickable');
        disabled = this;
        $(disabled).removeClass('clickable').addClass('active');
        $('#type').text('Support Staff');
    }
});
END COMMENT */

$('.teacher-link').click(function(){handle_click('.teachers','Teachers');});
$('.admin-link').click(function(){handle_click('.administrators','Administrators');});
$('.support-link').click(function(){handle_click('.support','Support Staff');});

function handle_click(target, target_text) {
    if (active != target) {
        $(active).hide();
        active = target;
        $(active).show();
        width = $(target + ' .staff-outer-container').children().size() * 180;
        $(target + ' .staff-outer-container').css('width', width + 'px');
        $(disabled).removeClass('active').addClass('clickable');
        disabled = this;
        $(disabled).removeClass('clickable').addClass('active');
        $('#type').text(target_text);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6AbR/

As you can see from my fiddle, the links dont turn grey after clicking. But if I remove the function and uncomment the script, they work again.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Please provide errors, expected vs actual outputs, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by breaks? What does the console say? What is the problem?

Comment: dont u want to use $(this) ?

Comment: @mlwacosmos: No, he probably doesn't

Comment: Just FYI, you can never "break" `this` as it is a reserved word and you cannot overwrite it with something else

Comment: [`$.proxy()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986329/understanding-proxy-in-jquery) may be useful to you here.

Comment: When clicking teacher-link or admin-link or support-link, It removes the class active and adds the class clickable to the previously clicked link, but it doesn't remove clickable and add class active to link i clicked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X6AbR/

Comment: @BrettMerrifield see my answer and let me know if it doesnt do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X6AbR/2/)**

The problem is when you register a handler the handler gets the the element on which user clciked as a `this` ... but when you call `handle_click` `this` becomes window object.

So solution is pass `this` as a parameter to `handle_click`

```
$('.teacher-link').click(function(){handle_click('.teachers','Teachers', this);}); // pass this  as a parameter... 

$('.admin-link').click(function(){handle_click('.administrators','Administrators', this);});
$('.support-link').click(function(){handle_click('.support','Support Staff', this);});

function handle_click(target, target_text, clickedElement) {
    if (active != target) {
        $(active).hide();
        active = target;
        $(active).show();
        width = $(target + ' .staff-outer-container').children().size() * 180;
        $(target + ' .staff-outer-container').css('width', width + 'px');
        $(disabled).removeClass('active').addClass('clickable');
        disabled = clickedElement;
        $(disabled).removeClass('clickable').addClass('active');
        $('#type').text(target_text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` is set based on how you call the function.

When you call a normal function like `handle_click(...)`, `this` becomes the global object.
You can call the function with a different `this` by calling `call`:

```
handle_click.call(customThis, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Alternatively, you could pass `this` as a normal parameter and use that parameter instead of `this` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would have had handleClick return a function specific to that handler: http://jsfiddle.net/X6AbR/1/

```
$('.teacher-link').click(createClickHandler('.teachers','Teachers'));
$('.admin-link').click(createClickHandler('.administrators','Administrators'));
$('.support-link').click(createClickHandler('.support','Support Staff'));

function createClickHandler(target, target_text) {
    return function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (active != target) {
            $(active).hide();
            ...
```

Though I'd probably instead store target and target_text, and the active/disabled in the DOM in the form of classNames and/or data attributes rather than passing them around, such as this answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16858484/400654. It'd be far more maintainable if you could just add another element in the DOM and your javascript automatically adapt to it.

Comment: You should rename that to `createClickHandler()`.